# Schema referencing stores the whole value instead of ObjectId alone

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Lately, I've been going through a course named **The Web Developer Course**.
In which the final project is based on Camps.
In the project, the **comment** database and the **campground** database are referenced, that is, the **ObjectIds** of the **comments** which are posted in a **campground** is stored in an **array**. This is what to be happened actually.

But in my case, the exact scenario's changed..When I try to Add a **new comment** what actually happens is that the **total object** gets stored in the **comments array** instead of the **ObjectId of the comment**. 
I've almost gone through Stackoverflow seeking solution for my problem but failed.

I just wanted the **ObjectId** to be stored in the **comments array** instead it stores the whole Object which brings me problem in **updating and deleting** a comment. When I delete or update a comment the operation does happen in the Comments database but doesn't reflect in the Campgrounds database. Please help me with this issue. If anyone's taking the same course, Please give me solutions if you've experienced something like this already. The Schema are as given below

**Campground Schema:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var campgroundSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    campGroundName: String,
    campGroundImage: String,
    description: String,
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment"
        }    
    ],
    addedBy: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Campground", campgroundSchema);
```

**Comment Schema:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

**Post request for creating a comment:**

```
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, createdComment) {
          if(err) {
              console.log(err);
          } else {
              createdComment.author.id = req.user._id;
              createdComment.author.username = req.user.username;
              createdComment.save();                  Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(err, foundCampground){
              foundCampground.comments.push(createdComment);
              foundCampground.save();
              req.flash("success" , "Comment created successfully");
              res.redirect("/index/" + req.params.id); 
             });
          }        
    });
});
```

The whole source code is below,

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmISAco3PGaPhQl_Riu8nroCom5h

Please help me fix this issue!

Answer (score 0):

you have this line:

```
foundCampground.comments.push(createdComment)
```

which is telling mongodb to store the whole comment in the array.

it should be this instead:

```
foundCampground.comments.push(createdComment._id)
```

which will only push the id property of the comment into the array.

Comment: That gives me an error in the showCamp page. It doesn't displays the comment out there. It's blank under the comments top.. My show camp page route is

`router.get("/:id", function(req, res) {
 Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(err, foundCampground) {
       if(err) {
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           res.render("campgrounds/showCamp", {campground: foundCampground});
       }
   });
});`

Comment: are you getting any errors on the console when you try to save? and more importantly, do you see the data being saved in mongodb?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors when I try to save.. The comment is getting updated properly in the comment collection and everything works just fine.

But it doesn't displays the comment in the showcamp page :(.. Can you please check for the showCamp.ejs from the my total source code which I uploaded in onedrive.

Comment: sorry, I should have been more explicit. I meant to ask if the id of the comment was being saved in the sub doc array on the campground.

Comment: can you go to http://gist.github.com and create a gist with the source from both your showcamp route and your showcamp ejs files? just post the link to the gist here and I'll take a look.

Comment: Yeah..It does save the ObjectId but stores em as separate Objects

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Blackdeathanton/2037e874dc0468a7093db4bf1a3aaf37   ROUTES

https://gist.github.com/Blackdeathanton/31771edca716fb1b52a80624b1af2c6c  SHOWCAMP PAGE

Comment: Did you find anything in my code? Is there any mistake?

Comment: Sorry, I added a comment to your gist. When you didn't respond I assumed you fixed it. Can you add a comment to the gist with the output of the following command in your mongo shell: db.campgrounds.find().pretty()

Comment: It just gives me an array on ObjectId each objectId is placed inside a separate Object

Comment: your schema is designed that way:

 comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment"
        }    

is that not what you want?

Comment: Nope I just want to reference the values in Comment object using it’s ObjectId.. I don’t understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

The version seemed to have a bug in it. 
The problem was fixed when I updated it. Fixed version is 5.0.3